# magento manage CRUD operations on custom tables on backend

Tags: magento, crud, multiple-tables, magento-1.7

I added 2 tables, for now, maybe will need more and I'm looking on how to add an administration page on the backend side. I found this SO question [Magento: Custom Module: How to Manage with Multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258084/magento-custom-module-how-to-manage-with-multiple-tables) that is extactly whay I need. The answer given is just, in my own words, `that's too dificult to achieve and too long to explain in SO`.

So, anyone willing to share some link, tutorial or DIY step by step explanation? I've already my models working and configured, thanks to @AlanStorm tutorials. I'm doing CRUD operations from within my code but I need to do it from backend on a window for administration purposes.

I thought this [Magento Custom CRUD Application Tutorial](http://www.amicontech.com/blog/magento-custom-crud-application-tutorial/) would help me but it involves using magento ModuleCreator plugin and is not working for me on magento 1.7.0.2. Also I already have my own module fully configured so lot of what module creator adds is not needed.

Found [this sample/tutorial/code](http://codemagento.com/2011/02/grids-and-forms-in-the-admin-panel/) but I'm having hard time following it, lot of obscure points and not sure what I'm doing, even if it is correct.

Comment: Backend CRUD is not as easy as frontend. I have used the tutorial you mentioned before (codemagento.com) and it helped me alot. You should take the time to read it and personalize the code, it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks @Ossie7, let's see what I can learn from all this, still new with magento but learning fast. Also, when commenting to leave a link write between [] the text and right next to the closing bracket add the link between parenthesis eg: [text](link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely benefit from some adminhtml grids, there are no shortage of tutorials [if you look for them](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=magento+adminhtml+grid).  I wrote my own which I now [shamelessly plug here](http://www.knectar.com/labs/ez-speedy-make-me-grid-admin-method-ey).

Comment: Nice one, didn't try to search for those terms, thanks. Will take a look and see what can I digg out.